# Move records to another table using LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I have suddenly faced a problem with moving some records in a SQL Server database from one table to another, using LINQ to SQL. Is it possible to write in LINQ to SQL a query just as simple as this:

```
INSERT INTO Table2 SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Selected = 1
GO

DELETE FROM Table1 WHERE Selected = 1
GO
```

without using loops and collections?

Comment: To be honest, this should be a stored procedure. Using LINQ for this would be overkill.

Comment: I had same problem, and solved my problem<br>
[See this answer. This worked for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48712294/move-record-from-a-table-to-another-using-foreach-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You absolutely don't need LINQ here. Consider performance & maintainability implications of issuing two SQL statements (or invoking a sproc) versus having to load potentially thousands of objects and then saving them back again.

Resort to `SqlCommand`s. That will be your best choice.

Comment: Thanks. It does look simpler doing that. Cheers.

Comment: Maybe wrap in a transaction? Maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of a way to move rows in Linq2Sql without a loop. :)

This kind of thing is much easier in SQL.  You can use the `output into` clause to move rows in a single statement:

```
delete from Table1
output deleted.id, deleted.name into Table2
where Selected = 1
```

Comment: InsertAllOnSubmit, DeleteAllOnSubmit - look no (explicit) loop (-: I quite agree that Linq to SQL is not the appropriate solution though.

Answer (score 0):

THis is just a simple insert and delete method which should written together.

One insert necessary fields to second table and when its finished, the second statement will remove the fields from first Table