# Move record from a Table to another using foreach in C#

Tags: c#, database, linq, foreach

My code

```
        tbl_Birthday tblB = new tbl_Birthday();
        string today = "01/10/2018";
        var query = from a in db.tbl_users.ToList() where a.birthday == today select a;
        if (query.Count() > 0)
        {
            foreach (var a in query.ToList())
            {
                tblB.name = a.name;
                tblB.score = a.core;
            }
            db.tbl_Birthdays.InsertOnSubmit(tblB);
            db.SubmitChanges();
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = from a in db.tbl_Birthdays select a;
```

This return just one record into  my DataGridView, but i have more then one record that conform this condition

Comment: move the insert inside the for loop maybe? Currently you loop through the list, and only set name and score, it would be the same if you would have `tblB.name = query.LastOrDefault()?.name` and `tblB.name = query.LastOrDefault()?.score`

Comment: Thanks, I have more then one record that conform the condition. If possible describe for me how can I fix it

Comment: You need to move the `SubmitChanges` inside the `foreach` loop. Currently your `foreach` loop is just setting the `name` and `score` properties over and over again, until it exits. Then you call `SubmitChanges` on a single item.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the `InsertOnSubmit` inside the `foreach` loop. Currently your `foreach` loop is just setting the `name` and `score` properties over and over again, until it exits. Then you call `SubmitChanges` on a single item:

```
foreach (var user in db.tbl_users.Where(user => user.birthday == "01/10/2018"))
{
    db.tbl_Birthdays.InsertOnSubmit(
        new tbl_Birthday{ name = user.name, score = user.score });
}

db.SubmitChanges();
```